# How can i add rating value in angular4

Tags: angular

When I add a value of rating it's still always 1 and this is my code:

```
<div class="star-rating col-sm-4 col-md-4"> 
   <div class="star-rating__wrap">
     <input #rating class="star-rating__input" id="star-rating-5" type="radio" name="rating5" value=""> 
     <label class="star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" for="star-rating-5" title="5 out of 5 stars"></label> 
     <input #rating class="star-rating__input" id="star-rating-4" type="radio" name="rating4" value="4"> 
     <label class="star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" for="star-rating-4" title="4 out of 5 stars"></label> 
     <input #rating class="star-rating__input" id="star-rating-3" type="radio" name="rating3" value="3"> 
     <label class="star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" for="star-rating-3" title="3 out of 5 stars"></label> 
     <input #rating class="star-rating__input" id="star-rating-2" type="radio" name="rating2" value="2"> 
     <label class="star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" for="star-rating-2" title="2 out of 5 stars"></label> 
     <input #rating class="star-rating__input" id="star-rating-1" type="radio" name="rating" value="1"> 
     <label class="star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" for="star-rating-1" title="1 out of 5 stars"></label> 
  </div> 
</div> 
<button (click)="addHost(nameHote.value,type.value,rating.value,contact.value,phone.value,email.value,adresse.value)" type="button" class="btn btn-add">
  Ajouter
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore the individual who downvoted your question (someone did it to mine today as well). I have therefore upvoted it to make it zero. This is a perfectly acceptable question to ask. Please try the following:

```
<div class="star-rating col-sm-4 col-md-4"> 
   <div class="star-rating__wrap">
     <input [(ngModel)]="ratingNumber" #rating class="star-rating__input" id="star-rating-5" type="radio" name="rating5" [value]=""> 
     <label class="star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" for="star-rating-5" title="5 out of 5 stars"></label> 
     <input [(ngModel)]="ratingNumber" #rating class="star-rating__input" id="star-rating-4" type="radio" name="rating4" [value]="4"> 
     <label class="star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" for="star-rating-4" title="4 out of 5 stars"></label> 
     <input [(ngModel)]="ratingNumber" #rating class="star-rating__input" id="star-rating-3" type="radio" name="rating3" [value]="3"> 
     <label class="star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" for="star-rating-3" title="3 out of 5 stars"></label> 
     <input [(ngModel)]="ratingNumber" #rating class="star-rating__input" id="star-rating-2" type="radio" name="rating2" [value]="2"> 
     <label class="star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" for="star-rating-2" title="2 out of 5 stars"></label> 
     <input [(ngModel)]="ratingNumber" #rating class="star-rating__input" id="star-rating-1" type="radio" name="rating" [value]="1"> 
     <label class="star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" for="star-rating-1" title="1 out of 5 stars"></label> 
  </div> 
</div> 
<button (click)="addHost(nameHote.value,type.value,ratingNumber,contact.value,phone.value,email.value,adresse.value)" type="button" class="btn btn-add">
  Ajouter
</button>
```

You were attempting to get the value via a variable, but all the radioboxes had the same variable name. Therefore you have to use ngModel to do this. I personally would have done this as a Reactive form but each to their own :)

You also need to declare your new 'ratingNumber' variable in the typescript:

```
ratingNumber: string;
```

Comment: i have this error : identifier ratingNumber is not defined?!

Comment: and this error : core.js:1427 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!